# Counting entries in a CSV file with python

Tags: python, csv, geopy

my CSV contains information about individuals and their date of death and their area of death. I am also using geopy to locate this area. This part is working [i think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254427/geocoding-with-geopy-and-big-data) but I don't really want to have the individuals but **I want the total bodycount per incident per day and per area.** So it gives me a CSV with information about the number of deaths, the geolocation, the date, and the area/province it happened in. Here is a snippet of my csv:

```
rowid,Name,Status,Sex,Province,Area,Date_of_Death,Cause_of_Death
1,Hasan Ali Saad al-Hareeri ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Daraa,Sawara,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
2,Riham Adnan Swais ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Homs,Telbeiseh,2015-12-10,Shelling
3,Ammar Ahmad al-Njoam ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Aleppo,Jarablus,2015-12-10,Explosion
4,Yaseen Slaiman al-Salkhadi ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Daraa,Jassim,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
5,Ayman Noman Qanatra ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Daraa,Jassim,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
6,Abdul Kareem Mohammad al-Tamki ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Daraa,Sheikh Miskeen,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
7,Ahmad Mohammad al-Tamki ,Civilian,Child - Male,Daraa,Sheikh Miskeen,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
8,Hamze Mohammad al-Tamki ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Daraa,Sheikh Miskeen,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
12,Ahmad Ibraheem al-Sayed Omar ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Aleppo,,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
13,Unidentified ,Civilian,Child - Male,Aleppo,Kafrnaya,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
14,Unidentified 1 ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Aleppo,Bazzaa,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
15,Unidentified 2 ,Civilian,Child - Male,Aleppo,Bazzaa,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
16,Unidentified 3 ,Civilian,Child - Male,Aleppo,Bazzaa,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
17,Mohammad Ahmad al-Farhoud ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Idlib,Telminis,2015-12-10,Shooting
23,wife of Faisal al-Ahmad al-Khaleefe ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Deir Ezzor,Qourieh,2015-12-10,Warplane shelling
24,Unidentified ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Takaya,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
25,Unidentified 1 ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Tabya Jazera village,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
26,Unidentified 2 ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Tabya Jazera village,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
27,Unidentified 3 ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Tabya Jazera village,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
28,Unidentified 4 ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Tabya Jazera village,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
29,Unidentified 5 ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Deir Ezzor,Tabya Jazera village,2015-12-10,Kidnapping - Execution
32,Amoun Murad ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
33,Kafa Mezweq ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
34,Hala Mohammad ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
35,Ahmad Mezweq ,Civilian,Child - Male,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
36,Ahlam Mezweq ,Civilian,Child - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
37,Adnan Hussain Haj Kheder ,Civilian,Child - Male,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
38,Wife of Hussain Haj Kheder ,Civilian,Adult - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
39,daughter of Hussain Haj Kheder 1 ,Civilian,Child - Female,Idlib,Jisr Shagour: Mraand,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
40,Muhammad Muhammad al-Aoutani ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Damascus Suburbs,Hamouria,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
41,Ibrahim al-Shami ,Civilian,Adult - Male,Damascus Suburbs,Hamouria,2015-12-09,Warplane shelling
```

Here is my code

```
import csv
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

geolocator = GoogleV3() #here some parameters are needed
lookups = {}
valueCounter = 0
init= True


with open('151213_Martyrs_filtered_civilian_2015_with_country.csv', 'rb') as csvinput:
    with open('151213_output_martyrs_final.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        output_fieldnames = ['Value','Country','Province','Area','Date_of_Death','Cause_of_Death','Latitude','Longitude']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, delimiter=',', fieldnames=output_fieldnames)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)
        for row in reader:
            if init == True :
                prevProvince = row['Province']
                prevArea = row['Area']
                prevDate = row['Date_of_Death']
                prevCause = row['Cause_of_Death']
                init = False
            if prevArea == row['Area'] and prevCause == row['Cause_of_Death'] and prevDate['Date_of_Death']:
                valueCounter +=1

                if row['Province'].split(' ', 1) == 'Damascus':
                    rowProv = "Damascus"
                else:
                    rowProv = row['Province']
                #here you have to replace the dict item by your csv column names
                query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, row['Area']))

                try:
                    address, (latitude, longitude) = lookups[query]
                except KeyError: # new lookup
                    try:
                        query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, rowProv))
                        address, (latitude, longitude) = lookups[query]
                        # print('lookup')
                    except KeyError: # search
                        try:
                            query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, row['Area']))
                            address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode(query)
                        except: # error
                            query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, rowProv))
                            address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode(query)
                        lookups[query] = address, (latitude, longitude)
                        print(query)

            else: #write down and save previous Row data
                output_row = {}
                output_row['Value'] = valueCounter
                output_row['Province'] = prevProvince
                output_row['Area'] = prevArea
                output_row['Date_of_Death'] = prevDate
                output_row['Cause_of_Death'] = prevCause
                output_row['Latitude'] = latitude
                output_row['Longitude'] = longitude
                writer.writerow(output_row)

                prevProvince = row['Province']
                prevArea = row['Area']
                prevDate = row['Date_of_Death']
                prevCause = row['Cause_of_Death']
                valueCounter = 1


                if row['Province'].split(' ', 1) == 'Damascus':
                    rowProv = "Damascus"
                else:
                    rowProv = row['Province']
                #here you have to replace the dict item by your csv column names
                query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, row['Area']))

                try:
                    address, (latitude, longitude) = lookups[query]
                except KeyError: # new lookup
                    try:
                        query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, rowProv))
                        address, (latitude, longitude) = lookups[query]
                        # print('lookup')
                    except KeyError: # search
                        try:
                            query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, row['Area']))
                            address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode(query)
                        except: # error
                            query = ','.join(str(x) for x in (rowProv, rowProv))
                            address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode(query)
                        lookups[query] = address, (latitude, longitude)
                        print(query)
```

What am I not seeing because it is not working?

Terminal gives me this message

```
    Test_stackoverflow_cached Ian$ python geopy_script_bodycount.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geopy_script_bodycount.py", line 22, in <module>
    if prevArea == row['Area'] and prevCause == row['Cause_of_Death'] and prevDate['Date_of_Death']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: You want to use pandas for doing such things in python

Comment: I am new to python. Any hint where to start?

Comment: This is a good introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otCriSKVV_8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do in that line, but the problem is in the one mentioned in by the trace:

```
if prevArea == row['Area'] and prevCause == row['Cause_of_Death'] and prevDate['Date_of_Death']:
```

Here `prevDate` is a string, not a dictionary like the `row` variable. You probably want to compare it something, like in the other clauses.

Comment: thank you i also took a look and now it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Doing this kind of things gets much easier using `pandas`, the python data munching and analysis library.

This is a good introduction: http://youtube.com/watch?v=otCriSKVV_8

And this will get you started with your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv',
    index_col='rowid',
    parse_dates=['Date_of_Death'],
)

# How many died at each day?
print('Deaths by date')
print(data.groupby('Date_of_Death').size())

# How many per area:
print('\nDeaths by Area')
print(data.groupby('Area').size())

# Or both:
print('\nPer date and Area')
print(data.groupby(['Date_of_Death', 'Area']).size())
```

Comment: I will keep this in mind and next time i'll try pandas. Thank you